# Does CMake has QMake's .qmake.conf alternative (automatically included file from parent directory) or other means to achieve similar result?

Tags: cmake

Let's say we have repository structure like this (note the `.qmake.conf` files):

```
repo/
├── libraries
│   └── libFoo
│       └── libFoo.pri
├── projects
│   ├── ProjectX
│   │   ├── apps
│   │   │   └── AppX
│   │   │       └── AppX.pro
│   │   ├── libs
│   │   │   └── libX
│   │   │       └── libX.pri
│   │   └── .qmake.conf
│   └── ProjectY
│       ├── apps
│       │   └── AppY
│       │       └── AppY.pro
│       └── .qmake.conf
├── qmake
│   └── common.pri
└── .qmake.conf
```

QMake supports `.qmake.conf` files, where you can declare useful variables, and it is **automatically included in your .pro file if found in parent directory**.

This is how it helps to avoid dealing with `../../..` relative paths, for example:

- Root `repo/.qmake.conf` file has `REPO_ROOT=$$PWD` declared.
- project also has it's own `repo/projects/ProjectX/.qmake.conf`, which has `include(../../.qmake.conf)` included and `PROJECT_ROOT=$$PWD` declared.
- project's application `.pro` file (`repo/projects/ProjectX/apps/AppX/AppX.pro`) can avoid writing `../../` and include all dependencies from sibling and parent directories like this:

```
 include($${REPO_ROOT}/qmake/common.pri)
 include($${REPO_ROOT}/libraries/libFoo/libFoo.pri)
 include($${PROJECT_ROOT}/libs/libX/libX.pri)
```

This is convenient and tidy. You DO have to write `../../` once (and update it if repository tree changes), but *only* once per new `.qmake.conf`, and later you can use variables to refer to various useful relative paths in the repository in any number of `.pro`'s you have.

Is three similar technique in CMake? How this kind of variable organization could be achieve with CMake, in most convenient way?

Comment: No, it doesn't, but really writing `include(my.cmake.conf)` is not that long either. And what's the point if you write the cmake configuration anyway?

Comment: Idea is to avoid hard-to-compile-in-head `../../......` paths. And your example is NOT a problem, but using and maintaining `include(../../../....../foo.conf)` is.

Answer (score 1):

In CMake you can achieve similar result somewhat differently:

(regarding "useful variables" management)

CMake knows about 3 "types of variables":

- vars with directory scope; directory scope variables behave in such a way that if you define them in some folder, they will automatically be visible in all subfolders. In brief, if you define some var in *root CMakeLists.txt*, it will be visible *in all project subfolders*. Example of defining "directory scope variable":

```
# outside any function
set(MY_USEFUL_VAR SOME_VALUE)
```

- vars with function scope; function scope variables are variables defined within the function. They are visible in the current function scope and all scopes initiated from it. Example of function scope variable:

```
function(my_function)
  # note that the definition is within the function
  set(MY_LOCAL_VAR SOME_VALUE)
  # rest of the function body...
endfunction()
```

- cache variables may be considered as "global variables", and those are also stored within `CMakeCache.txt` file within the root build folder. Cache variables are defined as follows (adding a new string variable):

```
set (MY_CACHE_VAR "this is some string value" CACHE STRING "explanation of MY_VAR")
```

Also, as already suggested within the comments, you can place variables definitions into the various "include files" and include them using CMake include statement.

In the end, here is the documentation about [set](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html), and [include](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include.html) CMake statements.

Comment: Thanks for quality post! Though that "root CMakeLists.txt" will only work if you always build *via* that .txt. My use case is that I open final project, like `repo/projects/ProjectX/apps/AppX/AppX.pro` with QtCreator and work directly with that Yes, the way is to include some `common.cmake` (like my example had `common.pri`), but to access it one needs to deal with these `../../../` paths, that are hard to maintain...

Comment: Hi, just for a sake of completeness, within QtCreator, one can open CMake-based project exactly the same way as qmake projects. Just do OpenProject, and then open CMakeLists.txt.